# Problems creat plugin woocommerce

Tags: php, plugins, woocommerce

I'm trying to make a plugin that will display a list of defined quantity on the article page. I have 2 problems:

1 / I can not seem to include the php file when a product is variable or simple.
2 / I would like to see the dropdown also in the cart page when the product is predefined quantity of

The purpose of the plugin is limited number of mini and maxi product

Here is the code I tried

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Woo Best Drop Down
Plugin URI: http://www.fr
Description: Drop Down
Version: 1.0
Author: xxx
Author URI: http://xxx.fr
*/


function tab_woo_drop_dwon() {
    ?>
    <li class="woo_best_drop_down_tab"><a href="#woo_best_drop_down_tab"><?php _e('Woo Best Drop Down', 'woo-best-drop-down'); ?></a></li>
<?php }
add_action('woocommerce_product_write_panel_tabs', 'tab_woo_drop_dwon');
function woo_tab_best_drop_down() {
    global $post;
    $woo_tab_best_drop_down = array(
    'hop' => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'woo_best_drop_down_text', true),
    'enabled' => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'woo_best_drop_down_enabled', true),
    );
    ?>

    <div id="woo_best_drop_down_tab" class="panel woocommerce_options_panel">
    <div class="options_group">
        <p class="form-field">      
    <?php woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array( 'id' => 'woo_best_drop_down_enabled', 'label' => __('Activer le seuil du stock faible?', 'woo-best-drop-down'), 'description' => __('Cochez la case pour activer le stock faible personalisé pour ce produit', 'woo-best-drop-down') ) ); ?>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="options_group woo_tab_best_drop_down">                                              
        <p class="form-field">
        <label><?php _e('Seuil du stock faible pour cet article', 'woo-icon-stock'); ?></label>
            <input type="textarea" name="woo_best_drop_down_text" value="<?php echo @$woo_tab_best_drop_down['hop']; ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Saisissez le seuil de stock', 'woo-best-drop-down'); ?>" />
        </p>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php }
add_action('woocommerce_product_write_panels', 'woo_tab_best_drop_down');
function woo_best_drop_down_custom_tab( $post_id ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'woo_best_drop_down_enabled', ( isset($_POST['woo_best_drop_down_enabled']) && $_POST['woo_best_drop_down_enabled'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'woo_best_drop_down_text', $_POST['woo_best_drop_down_text']); }
    add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_best_drop_down_custom_tab');



if ( $product->product_type == 'simple' ){include 'simple_drop_down.php';}
elseif ( $product->product_type == 'variable' ) {include 'variable_drop_down.php';}
?>
```

Simple drop dwon.php

```
<?php

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' , 'add_woo_best_drop_dwon');


function add_woo_best_drop_dwon(){
global $post,$product,$woocommerce;
    $truc = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'woo_best_drop_down_text', true);
    $values = explode(',',$truc);
    $validate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'woo_best_drop_down_enabled', true);
    if (( $validate == 'yes' ) ){
    echo "<style>.quantity.buttons_added {
    display: none !important;}</style><div class='quantity_select'><select name='quantity'>";

    foreach($values as $v){
    echo "<option value='$v'>$v</option>";}
    echo "</select></div>";

    }}

?>
```

Variable drop dwon.php

```
<?php

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_variation' , 'add_woo_best_drop_dwon');


function add_woo_best_drop_dwon(){
global $post,$product,$woocommerce;
    $truc = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'woo_best_drop_down_text', true);
    $values = explode(',',$truc);
    $validate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'woo_best_drop_down_enabled', true);
    if (( $validate == 'yes' ) ){
    echo "<style>.quantity.buttons_added {
    display: none !important;}</style><div class='quantity_select'><select name='quantity'>";

    foreach($values as $v){
    echo "<option value='$v'>$v</option>";}
    echo "</select></div>";

    }}

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Woop's sorry i have edit the post  !

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. i have creat one file for the variable and simple product. I have delete the file drop_down.php and simple_drop_down.php and i've creat drop_down.php and write this :

```
<?php

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' , 'add_woo_best_drop_dwon');


function add_woo_best_drop_dwon(){
global $post,$product,$woocommerce;
 $truc = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'woo_best_drop_down_text', true);
    $values = explode(',',$truc);
    $validate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'woo_best_drop_down_enabled', true);
    if (( $validate == 'yes' ) ){
    echo "<style>.quantity.buttons_added {
    display: none !important;}</style><div class='quantity_select'><select name='quantity'>";

    foreach($values as $v){
    echo "<option value='$v'>$v</option>";}
    echo "</select></div>";

    }}
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input' , 'add_woo_best_drop_down_variable');


function add_woo_best_drop_down_variable(){
global $post,$product,$woocommerce;
    $truc = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'woo_best_drop_down_text', true);
    $values = explode(',',$truc);
    $validate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'woo_best_drop_down_enabled', true);
    if (( $validate == 'yes' ) ){
    echo "<style>.quantity.buttons_added {
    display: none !important;}</style><div class='quantity_select'><select name='quantity'>";

    foreach($values as $v){
    echo "<option value='$v'>$v</option>";}
    echo "</select></div>";

    }}

?>
```

Now my probleme are in the cart.
If you go in the page cart the quantity is not drop down for the product selectioned.
Have an idea for  add the drop down quantity in the page cart?

Thanks